# window.open() has no effect in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to open new tab in a WKWebView, but when I call `window.open()` from javascript (using the Safari debug console for example), this has no effect.

I would expect it to trigger:

`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?`

But it does not.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        // ... add subview and setup constraints ...

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: someUrl))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        print("creates webview with")
        return WKWebView()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what would you expect from that javascript command actually in this environment? because this command usually should do nothing in such environment...

Comment: I would expect it to trigger the createWebViewWith method. That is the method supposed to be triggered when opening a new tab is requested.